# not by the servant

Tags: negation

a. The ring was stolen not by the servant. It was Tom who stole it.

b. The ring was stolen not by the servant. Tom stole it.

Are both of the above acceptable in formal English?

Are they acceptable in spoken English?

Comment: Why do you need a passive form?

Comment: Thank you. Well it is used sometimes, isn't it? I don't find it particularly strange.

Comment: Then, you probably already know this: The servant didn't steal the ring. The ring wasn't stolen by the servant.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lambie. and yes, I do know that. One could use either depending on the context. I suppose the active is more natural in most cases.

Comment: Why would you put the not in the wrong place, then? Unless there is a dialogue, or special emphasis, the not would not go there.  Here is an example of special emphasis: "The ring was stolen, not by Tom but by the servant."

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence in both examples is not idiomatic. You could say either

> The ring was not stolen by the servant

or, if someone suggested that the ring was not stolen at all,

> The ring was stolen, *but* not by the servant.

Either version of the second sentence is acceptable, but *It was Tom who stole it* emphasises the fact that you are naming him as the thief.

Comment: Although it would sound correct, if somewhat more formal, to say "The ring was stolen, not by the servant, but by Tom."

Comment: What @stangdon said. ***But*** the minimal change required to make OP's example idiomatic (although it's always going to be a bit "formal") is to simply extend the sentence immediately with a ***but-*** clause: *The ring was stolen not by the servant, **but by Tom*** (I have no particular opinion regarding the need for a comma / pause before ***but*** there). In conversational contexts, most of us would relocate the negation: *The ring **wasn't** stolen by the servant, but by Tom.*